# Python Numpy: beginning ending indexes of True value in boolean array

Tags: python, numpy

Good evening,

Is there a efficient way of getting all beginning and ending indexes of `True` values in a boolean array?
Let's say I have this array:

```py
x = np.array([nan, 11, 13, nan, nan, nan, 9, 3, nan, 3, 4, nan])
```

I use [`np.isnan(x)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) so I get:

```py
[True, False, F, T, T, T, F, F, T, F, F, T]
```

I would like to have at the end an array or list with only indexes of `NaN` -> i.e one index if single, or beginning index and ending index if consecutive `NaN` values:
`[0, [3, 5], 8, 11]`

Do I have to loop on the array myself and write a function or is there a numpy and efficient way of doing it?

I have already something running but as I have to deal with hundred of thousands of values per array and multiples array also, it takes time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
lst = []
for mask, grp in groupby(zip(np.arange(len(x)), np.isnan(x)), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    if mask == True:  # only for NaN
        idx = [idx for idx, _ in grp]
        lst.append([idx[0], idx[-1]] if len(idx) > 1 else idx[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
[0, [3, 5], 8, 11]
```

Comment: Woaw, 100k, congratz!!! :)

Comment: Now it is ;) congrats

Comment: Today I learned it rounds up... still a phenomenal achievement ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean operations shifting the `np.isnan` output on the left/right:

```
# if the value a NaN?
m = np.isnan(x)
# is the preceding value not a NaN?
m2 = np.r_[False, ~m[:-1]]
# is the following value not a NaN?
m3 = np.r_[~m[1:], False]

out = np.where((m&m2)|(m&m3))[0]
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  3,  5,  8, 11])
```